# Packets disappearing between forward and postrouting hooks

Tags: linux, networking, routing, netfilter

I can see packets getting logged/accepted in the `forward` chain and they're correctly tagged with the right outbound interface, but they never hit the rule in the `postrouting` chain and `tcpdump` never shows any packets leaving the interface. Per [this diagram](https://people.netfilter.org/pablo/nf-hooks.png) the routing decision has already happened (which is why it shows an outbound interface in the `forward` chain) and there's no further decisions to make between `forward` and `postrouting`. So what process is causing the packets to get dropped?

[image: nftables hooks]

Packets are arriving on a GRE tunnel on `eth1`, with this specific tunnel going to `source_interface`. The packets should leave out a Wireguard interface named `destination_interface`.

```
$ ip addr show source_interface
14: source_interface@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8973 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 10.1.0.219 peer 10.1.0.1
    inet 10.192.122.5/31 scope global source_interface
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5efe:a01:db/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip addr show destination_interface
15: destination_interface: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.192.122.3/31 brd 10.192.122.3 scope global destination_interface
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip tun
source_interface: gre/ip remote 10.1.0.1 local 10.1.0.219 ttl inherit key 168143513
```

The route table is setup such that there's a route sending these packets out `destination_interface`. This box is a bit interesting because it's a "bump in the wire" rather than a layer 3 router. So packets from a.b.0.0/16 will come in `source_interface` but should go out `destination_interface`. You'll have to trust me on this.

```
$ ip route
default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth1 metric 10001 
10.1.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.219 
10.192.122.2/31 dev destination_interface proto kernel scope link src 10.192.122.3 
10.192.122.4/31 dev source_interface proto kernel scope link src 10.192.122.5 
a.b.0.0/16 dev destination_interface scope link 

$ ip route get a.b.c.d from a.b.x.y iif source_interface
a.b.c.d from a.b.x.y dev destination_interface
    cache iif source_interface
```

I see the packets arrive. I see the routing decision happen. But between the `forward` and `postrouting` chains the packets disappear.

```
trace id f6179072 ip tablename prerouting packet: iif "source_interface" @ll,0,160 393920416270895464991677841829446786106534199515 ip saddr a.b.x.y ip daddr a.b.c.d ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 29177 ip length 128 udp sport 60448 udp dport 60449 udp length 108 @th,64,96 6499185482949407548864728065 
trace id f6179072 ip tablename prerouting rule iifname "source_interface" udp dport 60448-60449 counter packets 1341 bytes 118842 nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
trace id f6179072 ip tablename prerouting verdict continue 
trace id f6179072 ip tablename prerouting policy accept 
trace id f6179072 ip tablename forward packet: iif "source_interface" oif "destination_interface" @ll,0,160 393920416270895464991677841829446786106534199515 ip saddr a.b.x.y ip daddr a.b.c.d ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 63 ip id 29177 ip length 128 udp sport 60448 udp dport 60449 udp length 108 @th,64,96 6499185482949407548864728065 
trace id f6179072 ip tablename forward rule udp dport 60448-60449 counter packets 930 bytes 82380 (verdict continue)
trace id f6179072 ip tablename forward verdict continue 
trace id f6179072 ip tablename forward policy accept
```

I double checked that `forwarding` and `ip_forward` are on and (due to the bump-in-the-wire nature) that `rp_filter` is off. I've also turned on `log_martians` just in case; yet none are logged.

```
$ sysctl -a | egrep 'ipv4\.conf\.(all|default|source_interface|destination_interface)\.(forwarding|log_martians|rp_filter) |ipv4\.ip_forward '

net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.source_interface.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.source_interface.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.source_interface.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.destination_interface.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.destination_interface.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.destination_interface.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

There's nothing in the nftables other than the logging/counters:

```
bash-4.2# nft list tables 
table ip tablename
bash-4.2# nft list table tablename
table ip tablename {
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
        iifname "source_interface" udp dport 60448-60449 counter packets 41327 bytes 3657090 nftrace set 1
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type filter hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
        udp dport 60448-60449 counter packets 0 bytes 0
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        udp dport 60448-60449 counter packets 40916 bytes 3620628
    }
}
```

TCPDUMP:

```
$ tcpdump -c10 -i source_interface udp -lenn
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on elasticast, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
23:48:20.410079  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:20.514049  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:20.618069  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:20.722078  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:20.826039  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:20.930021  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:21.034045  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:21.138037  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:21.242025  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
23:48:21.346089  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 144: a.b.x.y.60448 > a.b.c.d.60449: UDP, length 100
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

```
$ timeout 30 tcpdump -c10 -i destination_interface udp -lenn
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes

0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I am able to reach the other end of the WireGuard tunnel:

```
$ ip route get 10.192.122.2
10.192.122.2 dev destination_interface src 10.192.122.3 uid 0 
    cache 
bash-4.2# ping -c2 10.192.122.2
PING 10.192.122.2 (10.192.122.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.192.122.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=19.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.192.122.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.412 ms

--- 10.192.122.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.412/10.043/19.674/9.631 ms
```

---

To reduce variables, I've routed a another network so the reverse path filtering should no longer be a factor. There's now an additional route for `w.x.y.0/24` via `source_interface` and the traffic is from `w.x.y.1` to `a.b.c.d`:

```
$ ip route show
w.x.y.0/24 dev source_interface scope link 
10.192.122.2/31 dev destination_interface proto kernel scope link src 10.192.122.3 
10.192.122.4/31 dev source_interface proto kernel scope link src 10.192.122.5 
a.b.0.0/16 via 10.192.122.2 dev wg0 

$ ip route get a.b.c.d from w.x.y.1 iif source_interface
a.b.c.d from w.x.y.1 via 10.192.122.2 dev destination_interface
    cache iif source_interface
```

I see the same behavior in the `nft monitor`:

```
trace id 1115829d ip tablename prerouting packet: iif "source_interface" @ll,0,160 393920389728870845158477693125073444177958731995 ip saddr w.x.y.1 ip daddr a.b.c.d ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 64 ip id 97 ip length 50 udp sport 60448 udp dport 60449 udp length 30 @th,64,96 6055826848460663089609086 
trace id 1115829d ip tablename prerouting rule iifname "source_interface" udp dport 60448-60449 counter packets 174010 bytes 15393938 nftrace set 1 (verdict continue)
trace id 1115829d ip tablename prerouting verdict continue 
trace id 1115829d ip tablename prerouting policy accept 
trace id 1115829d ip tablename forward packet: iif "source_interface" oif "destination_interface" @ll,0,160 393920389728870845158477693125073444177958731995 ip saddr w.x.y.1 ip daddr a.b.c.d ip dscp cs0 ip ecn not-ect ip ttl 63 ip id 97 ip length 50 udp sport 60448 udp dport 60449 udp length 30 @th,64,96 6055826848460663089609086 
trace id 1115829d ip tablename forward rule udp dport 60448-60449 counter packets 173045 bytes 15286564 (verdict continue)
trace id 1115829d ip tablename forward verdict continue 
trace id 1115829d ip tablename forward policy accept
```

I turned on `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/fib/enable` and I see the following, which looks correct. It can't find any routes in the local route table (255), but it correctly finds forward and reverse routes in the main route table (254).

```
          <idle>-0       [002] ..s. 12852.684790: fib_table_lookup: table 255 oif 0 iif 0 proto 0 0.0.0.0/0 -> a.b.c.d/0 tos 0 scope 0 flags 0 ==> dev - gw 0.0.0.0/:: err -11
          <idle>-0       [002] ..s. 12852.684793: fib_table_lookup: table 255 oif 0 iif 14 proto 0 w.x.y.1/0 -> a.b.c.d/0 tos 0 scope 0 flags 0 ==> dev - gw 0.0.0.0/:: err -11
          <idle>-0       [002] ..s. 12852.684793: fib_table_lookup: table 254 oif 0 iif 14 proto 0 w.x.y.1/0 -> a.b.c.d/0 tos 0 scope 0 flags 0 ==> dev destination_interface gw 10.192.122.2/:: err 0
          <idle>-0       [002] ..s. 12852.684794: fib_table_lookup: table 255 oif 0 iif 15 proto 0 a.b.c.d/0 -> w.x.y.1/0 tos 0 scope 0 flags 0 ==> dev - gw 0.0.0.0/:: err -11
          <idle>-0       [002] ..s. 12852.684794: fib_table_lookup: table 254 oif 0 iif 15 proto 0 a.b.c.d/0 -> w.x.y.1/0 tos 0 scope 0 flags 0 ==> dev source_interface gw 0.0.0.0/:: err 0


14: source_interface@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8973 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 10.1.0.219 peer 10.1.0.1
15: destination_interface: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/none
```